# Can't populate <div> with elements of a json_encoded php array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, getjson

This function worked previously (the last time I opened this project over a week ago), but now I can't seem to get it to work at all and I have no idea how to figure out what's going wrong! First, I'll diagram my file architecture in case my file paths are incorrect and causing my php to not even be called:

```
~/Sites
    proj1
        htdocs
            index.html
            ajax.php
            scripts
                java_script.js
            styles
                style_sheet.css
        includes
            scrapedImages
                .
                .
                .
```

Here's the JS function that uses AJAX to call a .php script:

```
function requestServer() {
    $.getJSON('/Users/aweeeezy/Sites/proj1/htdocs/ajax.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            var html = "<img src='/Users/aweeeezy/Sites/proj1/includes/scrapedImages/"+val+"' style='display:block;max-width:20px;max-height:20px;width:auto;height:auto' alt=null />"
            $('#puppy-box').prepend(html);
        });
    });
}
```

The line setting `var html` was `<img src='...'+images[i]+"...` when I first opened the project this morning, but I'm not sure why...I think because I was testing the site out, it was faster to only load a fraction of the images and used a for loop to cycle through only the first 10 or so pictures, hence the `i` index. Anyway, shouldn't it be `data[i]`, or `val[i]`...or `data[val]`? I have no idea what's going on here.

Here's the ajax.php file that the JS function is trying to call:

```
<?php
    $images = scandir('/Users/aweeeezy/Sites/proj1/includes/scrapedImages/');
    /*foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        if ($image == '.' || $image == '..') {
            unset($images[$key]);
        }
    }*/
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

I commented out the middle part because I wasn't sure if this was causing a complication. I tried putting both echo and print lines in here to see if the script is being called, but even if they are working, I can't really see them because they're being returned as `data` (I think) to the JS function that calls the script.

How do I even go about debugging this mess and get my girlfriend's valentine's day project back on track!

Comment: If you opoen a tab in your broser and put this /Users/aweeeezy/Sites/proj1/htdocs/ajax.php what does it show? Well, append the server name before of course http://blablabla/Users....

Comment: What I mean is that the scandir is correct because is from a local folder but the ajax call to the php is not correct because you have to call to a web server address not a local file path.

Comment: I think that AJAX works only on the web i.e over http request.

Comment: Use chrome, press f12 or whatever command key, go to network tab.. Reload the page. Look for a request with Ajax.php in it. Click on that particular item.. See if anything is returned in the response section.

Comment: @satchcoder, I'm sorry, where could I find the server name?

Comment: @satchcoder: Though it might be a good practice, it is not required.

Comment: @aweeeezy try this: `scandir('../includes/scrapedImages');` and this `print_r($images)` instead of `echo` and then alert() or console.log() recieved data in js.

Comment: Well, do you have an apache running? I don't know your settings, usually is http://localhost/blablalba but you need a server with php running in your system

Comment: @elf, here's a [http://imgur.com/qBfn2kD](screen shot) of the Inspector while making the request...again, the request used to be successful, not sure what changed :/

Comment: @satchcoder yes, apache is running and configured correctly, I can access my php config page and all that jazz. Plus, the ajax.php file is hosted on the server.

Comment: It says 403. What server are u running? A 403 most of the times indicates that the web server is configured to deny requests, may be through a particular ip. Check ur configurations'

Comment: @aweeeezy relative path will do the job: `scandir('../includes/scrapedImages');`

Comment: @aweeeezy In your screenshot I can see, that referer is `http://localhost/~aweeeezy/proj1/htdocs/` it means, that you can access your ajax.php file this way: `http://localhost/~aweeeezy/proj1/htdocs/ajax.php`

Comment: @MaximMazurok changing to `../includes/scrapedImages` fixed my php script so now the ajax call works as you can see [here](http://imgur.com/G8ph3ws). But I still can't get the images to populate the div.

Comment: Should I change `var html = "<img src='/Users/aweeeezy/Sites/proj1/includes/scrapedImages/"+data+"...` to `var html = "<img src='../includes/scrapedImages/"+data+"...`? I pretty sure `data` needs to be something else...maybe `data[val]'?

Comment: @aweeeezy  well, first you should use relative path with images too like so: `"<img src='../../includes/scrapedImages/"`

Comment: @aweeeezy also try this code to debug: `var html = key+" "+val+"<br>"` and send screenshot

Comment: @MaximMazurok It works now! `val` is the file name for each images so simply appending `val` to the relative path for the images did the trick. Everything works perfect now! My stress level is back to baseline, haha. Thanks so much :D